# Add source tree to xCode 4 project template

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates, xcode-template

I am creating a xcode 4 project template. I can get pretty much every thing I want in my project except a Source Tree reference.

I have a project in my xCode -> Preferences -> Source Tree which I want incorporated in my template without having to include the project in the Template Folder.

All i want to do is be able to add a reference to the source tree project.